# How to charge a 24 V battery driving a solar tracker (no AC available)

Tags: battery-charging, solar-energy

I am working on a solar tracker which will be located some distance from the inverter, and will not have AC available.

The motors driving the tracker will be DC, probably 24 or 48 V. The array panels have SolarEdge equalizers on them, and feed a SolarEdge inverter.

Is there a "good" way to drive the motors from the string output, which is somewhere around 375 V when operating?  For example, is it OK to connect a DC-DC converter to the string output without adversely affecting operation of the inverter, and then run an MPPT charger off that (obviously less power will be available from the inverter)?

[image: Block Wiring Diagram]

Comment: Welcome! A step down converter from each panel? Please draw a block diagram of what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Have one or two panels separated from the array to provide 24v through an mppt charge controller.

Comment: @Solar Mike  I would prefer not to separate panels as that reduces total output when no charging is necessary.  There is obviously a wide range of potential power requirement; a week of cloud-obscured weather vs a good sunny day.  Commercial trackers advertise ~1% of generated power.  That would be one small additional panel (array would have 18 300 W panels)  But one small panel would be insufficient in extended cloudy conditions.  The advantage of an AC connection is nothing wasted other than the conversion inefficiency.  I may end up having to run an AC line.

Comment: But how can you run an AC line? You stated clearly in your question that AC was not available.

Comment: @Solar Mike  I stated that because I would rather not run an AC line if I can help it.  I was thinking a DC-DC converter would be simple and do the job.  The nearest AC is ~150' away.  I'm going to have to trench to there to feed the HV DC array output to the inverter, so maybe it makes more sense to run the AC and use an AC-DC motor controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tiny windmill to power it. Just kidding...

### Add an auxiliary solar panel

and Morningstar's cheapest 24 V charge controller.

And, Bob's your uncle.

The difference is maintainability.  Anyone with an ounce of skill in solar can maintain this and no PPE is required. They may even have the parts on their truck.   Using a high voltage DC/DC requires a junction box and guarded enclosure, high voltage DC PPE because OSHA, and if it breaks will befuddle the maintainer who will probably scrap it and do this.

Also, this works if the panels are microinverters.

There is no reason to have any electrical connection between array and motor drive system.

Comment: What do you mean by a guarded enclosure?  I doubt if high voltage PPE is required.  When the inverter is powered off for service or due to loss of AC on the output side, power drops to <1 V per optimizer.  BTW, there are no microinverters in this installation.